# Special characters in string.Replace

Tags: c#, string

I want to replace special characters in string.

For example this is input text

http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fvideo.l3.fbcdn.net\u00252Fcfs-l3-ash4\u00252F351111\u00252F203\u00252F260478023976707_55781.mp4\u00253Foh\u00253D064626d4996116bdcde2d52f9b70e1f0\u002526oe\u00253D4E566C00\u002526l3s\u00253D20110823082632\u002526l3e\u00253D20110825083632\u002526lh\u00253D0dbcb2d22cd4dd5eb10bf

and then I expect this result : 
`http://video.l3.fbcdn.net/cfs-l3-ash4/351111...`

But string is not replacing as expected

```
string[] BadCharacters = { "\\u00253A", "\\u00252F", "\\u00253F" };
string[] GoodCharacters = { ":", "/", "?" };
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(BadCharacters[i], GoodCharacters[i]);
}
```

Comment: No assumptions were made. What do you mean? However, I just rolled back the last edit, that changed his code.

Comment: No assumptions were made.  His code was cut-and-pasted and not marked as a code block.  He had the escape characters IN the text of the message, but since wasn't marked as a code block the \\ showed as a \

Comment: Nevermind, I see now.  He marked it as a quote instead of a code block.

Comment: @Abe: Please see the edit history before making any accusations, will you? You will clearly see, that the code was **not** changed. But only after the edit it showed correctly.

Comment: @Daniel, I looked at the edit history before I made my "accusation".  I simply didn't realize that he had put his original code in a quote block rather than a code block.  This made it appear that you just added a slash.  Rest assured I will try to get clarification when I am confused on an edit regardless of whether that hurts your feelings or not.  I would also point out that I tried to get clarification rather than just blindly rolling back.  Your welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is your string gets stomped every iteration through the loop by going back to TextBox1.Text, you need to keep it in a local and keep using the changed value for the next substitution:

```
var changedText = textBox1.Text;

// always modify and assign to temp, that way we modify previous
for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
  changedText = changedText.Replace(BadCharacters[i], GoodCharacters[i]);
}

textBox2.Text = changedText;
```

Comment: p.s.  I also submitted this answer on the MSDN forums if you haven't seen it yet: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/53cc7d80-39f6-4368-b25f-561d9f95546b

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var tmp = textBox1.Text;
for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    tmp = tmp.Replace(BadCharacters[i], GoodCharacters[i]);
}

textBox2.Text = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the updated value of string each time you replace a substring. So save initial value of `textBox1` to `textBox2` and use it during iteration. In this way, you won't lose your updated string value.

```
textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;

for(i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
   textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text.Replace(BadCharacters[i], GoodCharacters[i]);
}
```

Also, by asssigning initial `textBox1` value to `textBox2` and using it inside your for loop, you save one assigmant statement.

Answer (score 0):

textBox2.Text will only ever contain one of the substitutions for each loop, so you likely see only the last iteration.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
  textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(BadCharacters[i], GoodCharacters[i]);
}
```

would likely provide the full substituted string desired.